# Same first node

Tags: circuit, guard

In TOR Browser 6.5.2 if I do 'New Tor Circuit for this site', I get the same first node and IP address on the new circuit every time I hit new circuit. It always used to differ.

If I quit out of TOR and go back in it's always the same first node. Checked with a couple of friends and their 6.5.2 browsers are doing exactly the same. The first node and IP isn't the same as the one I'm getting but it remains constant for them no matter how many times New Circuit is chosen or if they quit and go back in.

Is anyone else seeing this?